# Ruby using self in accessor method causes SystemStackError

Tags: ruby

I don't get this, when I try to run below code, I am getting

***employee.rb:55:in `hourly_wage=': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)***

```
class HourlyEmployee < Employee
    attr_reader :hourly_wage, :hours_per_week

    def hourly_wage=(hourly_wage)
        self.hourly_wage = hourly_wage
    end

    def hours_per_week=(hours_per_week)
        self.hours_per_week = hours_per_week
    end

    def print_pay_stub
        print_name
        pay_for_period = (hourly_wage) * (hours_per_week) * 2
        formatted_pay = format("$%.2f", pay_for_period)
        puts "Pay for this period: #{formatted_pay}"
    end
end
```

Isn't this basically the same in Java where I use the this keyword in the setter method?

If I replaced the def with then everything works fine.

```
def hourly_wage=(hourly_wage)
        @hourly_wage = hourly_wage
    end
```

Sorry, just started picking up Ruby

Comment: in your case you dont need to implement `def hourly_wage=` and `def hours_per_week=`. You can simly change `attr_reader :hourly_wage, :hours_per_week` to `attr_accessor :hourly_wage, :hours_per_week`

Comment: @sig sorry..forgot to mention that there will be validations there..I just remove it for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can imagine that `hourly_wage=` is a method name

your code:

```
def hourly_wage=(hourly_wage)
  self.hourly_wage = hourly_wage
end
```

if you replace the name `hourly_wage=` with `assign`, it'll become:

```
def assign(hourly_wage)
  self.assign(hourly_wage)
end
```

you recursively call yourself without a break-point, so it raise `stack level too deep` exception.

Comment: "you can imagine that `hourly_wage=` is a method name" – There is no need for imagination. `hourly_wage=` is a method just like any other method.

Comment: Yup, but is good to help the new ruby users to understand how the lang works, take acount that the user comes from java, so there's many changes in the syntax which he doesn't know about. I don't see any issue with explaining it like this

Answer (score 0):

You are recursively calling `hourly_wage=` in `hourly_wage=`, with no termination condition, so you are recursing infinitely. Since Ruby does not have Proper Tail-Recursion, you will at some time run out of stack space.

> Isn't this basically the same in Java where I use the this keyword in the setter method?

Yes, it is exactly the same as this equivalent Java code:

```
void setHourlyWage(BigDecimal hourlyWage) {
  this.setHourlyWage(hourlyWage);
}
```

This will have the exact same result: a stack overflow.

> If I replaced the def with then everything works fine.
>
> ```
> def hourly_wage=(hourly_wage)
>   @hourly_wage = hourly_wage
> end
> ```

This is something completely different. Here you are not recursively calling `hourly_wage=` but instead simply assigning to an instance variable ("field" in Java jargon).